# Downloads ending too soon

Tags: firefox, download

Files and videos that I try to download and load are sometimes ending before the entire file is actually downloaded. Shows no errors in download manager for Firefox, and it seems to happen to files that are maybe more than 10MB in size.

Can't use Chrome since its not supported in my country, and I am connected through a proxy.

Comment: I've also noticed this behaviour from time to time. Downloads, and then just reports a finished download, although the file is not finished, right ?

Comment: how often is sometimes? how steady is your internet connection?

Comment: just curious - what country doesn't have chrome?

Comment: My connection seems pretty steady, but since its slow i just stream radio sometimes, which runs fine. But the longer the video takes to DL the higher the chance for it to terminate it seems.

I am in Syria, google said I was not supported and could not DL :(

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the connections timeout and firefox download manager just terminates the download. This leaves incomplete downloads.

You should use a download manager (something like [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/201)).
Alternatively use [wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm) which allows you to continue from an incomplete download (look at [WinWGet](http://cybershade.us/winwget/)).
<sup>DownThemAll can also be paused and will continue from where it left off</sup>

Comment: +1 - DTA 'just works', pause and resume can be useful, choosing how many threads to run at once can improve performance as well, although high numbers may not be supported by the target site (eg downloading BBC podcasts always seems to take exactly the same amount of time, and it used to take me up to half an hour for a half hour programme. Stoopid).
DTA can still time out though, but will resume from where it left off as long as you don't restart FF in the mean time

Comment: @AdamV, that's odd, I think I have restarted FF on a paused download to continue from the pause. Are you sure it does not allow that too?